# How to get a token from the backend in Angular2 when using separate development?

Tags: angular, token, csrf, httpbackend

The backend returns the token in the html code and I can't get it out

```html
<meta name="sessid" content="900959d22b2a4724a31425fad1895fbf">
```

Angular2 has its own page index.html in development mode (called ng serve)

Comment: How are you requesting the token from the backend?

Comment: you could search the body: `const matches = body.match(/meta name="sessid" content="(.+?)"/)`

Comment: If you include the compiled angular result on the html output page (backend php), then you can extract data from the meta tag or some any. But when developed separately from backend, when call ng serve (localhost:4200), index.html does not contain a token (there is only static).

Comment: Check the sample here https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/